# dynamic mysql Query based on user input

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that currently sums data by month:

```
    $sql = SELECT SellerName, 
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201201, 1,0)) AS Jan, 
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201202, 1,0)) AS Feb, 
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201203, 1,0)) AS Mar, 
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201204, 1,0)) AS Apr, 
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201205, 1,0)) AS May, 
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201206, 1,0)) AS Jun,
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201207, 1,0)) AS Jul,
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201208, 1,0)) AS Aug,     
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201209, 1,0)) AS Sep,
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201210, 1,0)) AS Oct,      
           SUM(IF(ReportMonth = 201211, 1,0)) AS Nov,    
           COUNT(*) AS YTD
           FROM onlineDATA
           WHERE BuyerZipCode IN ($zips_query) 
           GROUP BY SellerName
```

This works great.

But, I need to adjust it to allow for user input on the months - i.e. user will select start and end months.

I can format the datepicker data into the existing yyyymm format - but how would I formulate the query in PHP to adjust for variable months and accounting for multiple years (e.g. oct 2012 to Feb 2013)?

Thanks!

Comment: I should have added the table this creates has Sellers down the left, and the months are the headers.  The user will dictate how many columns are in the table based on the start and end months.  SO I am OK if the headers go:  Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb etc. when the user crosses into a new year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will only work for a single year; otherwise you'll need additional columns if you do not want months from multiple years grouped together. You should also use `date` functions rather than checking an integer value (you shouldn't be storing date as an int).

If you need a dynamic approach, you will need to do the dynamic query preparation on the PHP side (take the start/end date and generate the SQL).

Here may be a solution you're looking for:

```
<?php

$startDate = '201201';
$endDate = '201303';

$formattedStartDate = strtotime( SUBSTR($startDate, 0, 4) . '-' . SUBSTR($startDate, -2, 2) . '-01' );
$formattedEndDate = strtotime( SUBSTR($endDate, 0, 4) . '-' . SUBSTR($endDate, -2, 2) . '-01' );

$sql = "SELECT SellerName, \n";

while ($formattedStartDate <= $formattedEndDate) {
    $sql .= 'SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = ' . date('Y', $formattedStartDate) . ' AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = ' . date('m', $formattedStartDate) . ")) AS '" . date('M Y', $formattedStartDate);

    if($formattedStartDate <> $formattedEndDate) {
        $sql .= "', \n";
    }
    else {
        $sql .= "'\n";
    }

    $formattedStartDate = strtotime('+1 month', $formattedStartDate);
}

$sql .= 'COUNT(*) AS YTD
FROM onlineDATA
WHERE BuyerZipCode IN ($zips_query) 
GROUP BY SellerName';

echo $sql;
```

**Result**

```
SELECT SellerName, 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 01)) AS 'Jan 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 02)) AS 'Feb 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 03)) AS 'Mar 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 04)) AS 'Apr 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 05)) AS 'May 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 06)) AS 'Jun 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 07)) AS 'Jul 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 08)) AS 'Aug 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 09)) AS 'Sep 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 10)) AS 'Oct 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 11)) AS 'Nov 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2012 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 12)) AS 'Dec 2012', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2013 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 01)) AS 'Jan 2013', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2013 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 02)) AS 'Feb 2013', 
SUM(IF(LEFT(ReportMonth, 4) = 2013 AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 03)) AS 'Mar 2013'
COUNT(*) AS YTD
FROM onlineDATA
WHERE BuyerZipCode IN ($zips_query) 
GROUP BY SellerName
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.org/rCzhuLGq)

Comment: I am ok with months from multiple years together - apologies if the original question was sketchy on that.  Assume I can change the ReportMonth field to a date field - I still need to sum all sales in a given month - and adjust for the months selected by the user.  A user could select 1 month, 3 months, 24 months - or anything in between

Comment: That will work - thanks a ton.  I made one small change - I need a ", 1, 0" here: "AND RIGHT(ReportMonth, 2) = 01, 1, 0))...

Comment: Also - because of the COUNT(*) I did not need the if/then statement.  I needed a "," at the end of all the "SUM"s

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, I'm sure something like this is a start:

```
SELECT SUM(ReportMonth) FROM SellerName
WHERE BuyerZipCode IN ($zips_query)
AND ReportMonth > '$start_date'
AND ReportMonth < DATE_ADD('$start_date', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY ReportMonth
```

e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(ReportMonth) FROM SellerName
WHERE BuyerZipCode IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
AND ReportMonth > '2013-01-01'
AND ReportMonth < DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY ReportMonth
```